# How do I get cloudfront to serve a file instead of redirecting to the originating S3 Bucket when the Accepts: gzip header is passed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket containing some files. This serves as the origin for a Cloudfront distribution.

Whenever I try to access these files via Chrome, Chrome automatically adds a header saying it will accept the gzipped version. This leads Cloudfront to redirect the request to the S3 bucket, so I lose out on the benefit provided by Cloudfront, rendering it useless. These are files of a proprietary format.

If I do a curl request and omit the header relating to gzip compression, Cloudfront will serve me the file instead of redirecting. This is what I want in Chrome too, but I can't force Chrome to change its request headers without changing some flags, which is not an option in my use-case.

How do I get Cloudfront to serve me the file instead of redirecting me to the bucket?

Comment: Have you configured gzip support correctly in CloudFront by following the instructions here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

Comment: CloudFront does not generate redirects.  It could, however, return a cached redirect from a misconfiguration that you had earlier but fixed since then.  Can you capture and show us all the response headers from this redirect?

Comment: I am facing the same issue: any chance you manage to solve it ?
Here are the response headers I get when adding gzip headers:
```HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect```
`Content-Type: application/xml`
`Connection: keep-alive`
`Location: http://****.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.txt`
`Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 13:16:51 GMT`
`Server: AmazonS3`
`Age: 65141`
`X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront`
`Via: 1.1 7596eaeceb83bcb64b8079e7ca9ec456.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)`
`X-Amz-Cf-Id: Pf3rSjIx938aQoAGI34FXISKhvwNvrg7sSoZblk_1xkrVl1SLJb_HA==
}`